# Upgrading Andy Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, andyroid

I am new to Andyroid Emulator. The current Android version on the device is 4.2.2. Is there an option to update to a later Android version? Recommendations for emulator alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @burntsugar After some search for emulators,there are quite a number of them available but among the top 3 was Blue Stacks,Andy,Amiduos,i found AMIDuos emulator fit my box.As this has lollipop version(APK 5.0 most supported one) as well as jelly bean version and also apk installation is easy.You chan check [their](http://amiduos.com/downloads) download page.